# Batch convert Powerpoint single-slide presntations to JPEG

Tags: image, applescript, powerpoint, batch-processing, automator

In search of Automator or Applescript to batch convert Powerpoint Presentations with a single slide to an image file (preferably JPEG).

I am using Powerpoint 2011 for Mac and I am running OS X Yosemite. A

Comment: Since you have PowerPoint, is there some objection to using VBA in PowerPoint itself to do the job?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `unoconv` which is part of LibreOffice to convert to PDF and then ImageMagick to convert from PDF to JPG.

Both these tools can be installed on OSX using `homebrew`, i.e.

```
brew install imagemagick
```

The command would then be

```
unoconv someFile.ppt someFile.pdf
convert -density 144 someFile.pdf someFile.jpg
```

I wouldn't use AppleScript to batch this, I would use `find` from the `bash` shell in Terminal like this

```
find . -iname "*.ppt" -exec unoconv "{}" "{}.pdf" \;
```

Comment: Thanks, works in 2020 with one change, `unoconv -f pdf -o someFile someFile.pptx`. Unoconv will go directly to JPG, but using `convert` to go from intermediate PDF is better quality, even without using `-density` option.

Answer (score 0):

After weeks trying to, I find a way to batch convert an entire folder of pptx files into jpg (one slide each) with the same name as original each file. ITs windows using VBA. He goes, don't mind the non-code part I just changed the code and mix many that I find out there.

```
Sub BatchSave()
' Opens each PPT in the target folder and saves as PPT97-2003 format

    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim sPresentationName As String
    Dim oPresentation As Presentation
    Dim osld As Slide

    ' Get the foldername:

    sFolder = InputBox("Folder containing PPT files to process", "Folder")

    If sFolder = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Make sure the folder name has a trailing backslash
    If Right$(sFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        sFolder = sFolder & "\"
    End If

    ' Are there PPT files there?
    If Len(Dir$(sFolder & "*.PPTX")) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Bad folder name or no PPT files in folder."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Open and save the presentations
    sPresentationName = Dir$("*.PPTX")
    While sPresentationName <> ""
        Set osld = ActiveWindow.View.Slide
        osld.Export sPresentationName & ".jpg", "jpg"

        ' New presentation is now saved as N_originalname.ppt
        ' Now let's rename them - comment out the next couple lines
        '   if you don't want to do this
        ' Original.PPT to Original.PPT.OLD
        'Name sFolder & sPresentationName As sFolder & sPresentationName & ".OLD"
        ' N_Original.PPT to Original.PPT
        'Name sFolder & "N_" & sPresentationName As sFolder & sPresentationName
        sPresentationName = Dir$()
    Wend

    MsgBox "DONE"

End Sub
```